# Struggling with MySQL and PHP form, can't print results

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I have tried to write a form that queries the database and then returns products that fit the criteria.

I have created a new Wordpress Template and also created a new /results.php page for it to load to. However, I am getting no results printed out whatsoever.

What am I doing wrong here?

Cheers

```
    <form action="results.php" method="get">
    <input type="text" name="search">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Search">
    </form>

    <?php
    $server = 'localhost';
    $user = '';
    $password = '';
    $dbname = '';


    $connection = mysqli_connect("localhost",$user,$password,$dbname);

    if(!$connection){
        echo "Connection ERROR ".mysqli_connection_error();

    }

    $select = ("
SELECT * 
  FROM Products 
 WHERE product LIKE '%".$search."%'
    OR price LIKE '%".$search."%'
";

    $run = mysqli_query($select);

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($run)) {
        $product = $row['Product'];
        $price = $row['Price'];
        $store = $row['Store'];

        echo "Available ".$product."";
        echo "Price ".$price."";
        echo "At ".$store."";

    }
    ?>
```

Comment: Small protip note: do _not_ compose that `$select` the way you are doing now. Use a [prepared statement](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) so that you can at least reasonably trust the templating to not [drop your database](https://xkcd.com/327/).

Comment: Thanks @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans still struggling with that. This is what you get when you try to change careers through Udemy...

Comment: And never use `SELECT *` . Instead, always name and qualify the columns you actually want returned. It also helps immensely with debugging.

Comment: try POST method with $search = $_POST['search']; or try the get method with a URL $search = $_GET['search']; search.php?search=<product name>

Answer (score 0):

```
$select = ("
SELECT * 
  FROM Products 
 WHERE product LIKE '%".$search."%'
    OR price LIKE '%".$search."%'
";
```

I guess the first parenthesis it is an error. We don't have enough information to solve this. Maybe we need a couple of examples of your table. Try to run this query in your mysql in order to check if there is any output.

Maybe you should use PDO class.

Not sure if there is negative impact but I prefer to use this way to generate queries:

```
$select = <<<TEMPLATE
    SELECT * FROM ´mytable´
    WHERE `myfield` LIKE ?
TEMPLATE;
```

? can be "%$search%". Allows you reuse the query. PDO takes care of parameters you pass and replace them into each ?.

Finally try to print your $_POST in order to check if what user type and you receive is what you expect.

Answer (score 0):

```
<form action="" method="POST">
  <input type="text" name="search">
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Search">
</form>

<?php
$server = 'localhost';
$user = 'db-username';
$password = 'db-password';
$dbname = 'db-name';

$connection = mysqli_connect($server,$user,$password,$dbname);
if(!$connection){
    echo "Connection ERROR ".mysqli_connection_error();
}


$search = $_POST['search'];
// or use $_POST['search'] directly in your sql query

// check if search submitted... if so continue.
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM Products WHERE product LIKE '%".$search."%' OR price LIKE '%".$search."%';";
  $result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql);

  // see if we got at least 1 result before continuing...
  if (mysqli_num_rows($result)>0) {
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $product = $row['Product'];
        $price = $row['Price'];
        $store = $row['Store'];

        echo "Available ".$product;
        echo "Price ".$price;
        echo "At ".$store;
    }
  }
}
```

Hope this helps you out, please note to sanitize any user inputted data etc, and as stated above in a comment prepaired statements are the way to go - but you can work on that once you get a working solution. If you get no output, check your sql query etc are correct.